# Warning message on creation of new column in pandas - slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

In Python 3 and Pandas I have this dataframe:

```
te_cnpjs.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1255 entries, 0 to 5663
Data columns (total 13 columns):
DATA_LS               856 non-null object
DATA_INCLUS           789 non-null object
Proprietario          1255 non-null object
Nome_propriedade      1255 non-null object
Municipio             1253 non-null object
Estado                1253 non-null object
CNPJ_CPF_CEI          1255 non-null object
CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo    1255 non-null float64
Trab_Envolv           995 non-null float64
Ramo_atividade        540 non-null object
Localizacao           527 non-null object
Cod_ativ              563 non-null object
Tipo_lista            1255 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), object(11)
memory usage: 137.3+ KB
```

The column "CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo" has codes of 13 or 14 digits: "6158959000136", "78141843000103", "4773160000000", "78231701000986"...

I created a new column from the column "CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo", but only with its 8 first numbers

But I received warning messages: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

First I turned the "CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo" column into integer:

```
te_cnpjs['CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo'] = te_cnpjs.CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo.astype('int64')
/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/RB/te/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Then I created the new column, "CNPJ_raiz", with only the first eight numbers:

```
te_cnpjs['CNPJ_raiz'] = te_cnpjs['CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo'].astype(str).str[:8]
/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/RB/te/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

The result was expected, it worked. But I want to understand if the warning message can mean if what I'm doing has some risk of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a warning designed to warn users that when you index your dataframes with ['colname'] convention, the behaviour might not be consistent (though it is for most cases). Check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) for a more detailed explanation with examples.